# No Youtube embedded videos here?

Tags: support, answers

I tried to embed two YouTube videos in [my answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/85389/3106), but they don't show.

Don't these work here, or did I put in an invalid link?

Comment: As far as I know only a few sites have embedded videos enabled. SciFi, gaming, music and movies as far as I know. And Anime wanted this feature enabled, but I think they don't have it. So no, you can't embed videos here. You can only link to the videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube embedding is not available by default on Stack Exchange.  A few sites have made requests to have it turned on, so it's possible.  (It's kind of like MathJax in that regard, I guess.)

In general, a request to enable a special feature should take the form of a feature request that lays out the case for its benefit on the site in question.  I assume there's some downside to YouTube embedding, some reason they don't just enable it everywhere.  I think that the sites that have it had to show that it added significant value.  I see how that could easily be the case on Movies & TV or Music; it's less obvious to me for Worldbuilding.  Which doesn't mean it's not; I haven't thought much about it, nor reviewed the [186 occurrences of www.youtube.com on main](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=www.youtube.com).

I suggest looking for the feature-request meta posts on the sites that have it to see what they did.